# Mean of Very Small Values

Tags: matlab, precision

I'm trying to compute the log of the mean of some very small values. For the current data set, the extreme points are

```
log_a=-1.6430e+03;
log_b=-3.8278e+03;
```

So in effect I want to compute `(a+b) / 2`, or `log((a+b)/2)` since I know `(a+b)/2` is too small to store as a double.

I considered trying to pad everything by a constant, so that instead of storing `log_a` I'd store `log_a+c`, but it seems that `a`and `b` are far enough apart that in order to pad `log_b` enough to make `exp(log_b+c)` computable, I'd end up making `exp(log_a+c)` too large.

Am I missing some obvious way to go about this computation? As far as I know MATLAB won't let me use anything but double precision, so I'm stumped as to how I can do this simple computation.

EDIT: To clarify: I can compute the exact answer for these specific values. For other runs of the algorithm, the values will be different and might be closer together. So far there have been some good suggestions for approximations; if an exact solution isn't practical, are there any other approximations for more general numbers/magnitudes of values?

Comment: I'm a little confused. Wouldn't `(exp(log_a) + exp(log_b)) / 2` just be the average of `a` and `b`?  The log of the mean of the original values would be more like `log((a+b)/2)` (although to get the mean of the values, you can't just take the extrema and average them).

Comment: Yes, you're right; sorry for the confusion. I am interested in the average of `a` and `b`, but I know that both `a` and `b` are too small to represent as doubles, so I am in effect looking for `log((a+b)/2)` rather than `(a+b)/2`.

Comment: Ah, I see.  As Mysticial points out, because the magnitude of `a` and `b` are so different, adding them together won't actually affect the value of `a` for several hundred decimal places (well outside double precision), so `log((a+b)/2)` degrades to `log(a/2)` or `log_a-log(2)`.

Comment: have you considered variable precision arithmetic with the Symbolic Toolbox?

Comment: I just updated my answer with a full algorithm that should do exactly what you want without any precision loss.

Comment: I just added an even simpler solution to my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mystical has the right idea but for a more general solution that gives you the log of the arithmetic mean of a vector `log_v` of numbers already in the log domain use:

```
max_log = max(log_v);
logsum = max_log + log(sum(exp(log_v-max_log)));
logmean = logsum - log(length(log_v));
```

This is a common problem in statistical machine learning, so if you do a Google search for `logsum.m` you'll find a few different versions of MATLAB functions that researchers have written for this purpose. For example, [here's a Github link](https://github.com/ronw/matlab_hmm/blob/master/logsum.m) to a version that uses the same calling conventions as `sum`.

Comment: I agree, this is the best solution to the general problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Well, `exp(log_b)` is so much smaller than `exp(log_a)` that you can completely ignore that term and still get the correct answer with respect to double-precision:

```
exp(log_a) = 2.845550077506*10^-714
exp(log_b) = 4.05118588390*10^-1663
```

If you are actually trying to compute `(exp(log_a) + exp(log_b)) / 2`, the answer would underflow to zero anyways. So it wouldn't really matter unless you're trying to take another logarithm at the end.

If you're trying compute:

```
log((exp(log_a) + exp(log_b)) / 2)
```

Your best bet is to examine the difference between `log_a` and `log_b`. If the difference is large, then simply take the final value as equal to the larger term - log(2) since the smaller term will be small enough to completely vanish.

EDIT:

So your final algorithm could look like this:

1. Check the magnitudes. If `abs(log_a - log_b) > 800`. Return `max(log_a,log(b)) - log(2)`.
2. Check either magnitude (they will be close together at this point.). If it is much larger or smaller than 1, add/subtract a constant from both `log_a` and `log_b`.
3. Perform the calculation.
4. If the values were scaled in step 2. Scale the result back.

EDIT 2:

Here's an even better solution:

```
if (log_a > log_b)
    return log_a + log(1 + exp(log_b - log_a)) - log(2)
else
    return log_b + log(1 + exp(log_a - log_b)) - log(2)
```

This will work if `log_a` and `log_b` are not too large or are negative.

Comment: This is a good answer, and does comfort me somewhat. However, in general the values could be somewhat closer together in other runs of the algorithm (see the clarification in my question). I think a combination of this and my previous idea might work, though. In particular: add `c` to all the values such that largest ones become computable; compute `log(mean(exp(x+c)))-c`; the values that still underflow can be assumed to be too small to affect the calculation. Let me ponder a little more, but I think this will work out. Thanks!

Comment: If the values are close enough to where it matters, but large/small enough to where `exp()` will over/underflow, then yes, you will need to scale the values up/down so that they won't overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't like my previous suggestion of completely changing platforms and are looking for an approximation, why not just use the geometric mean (exp((log_a+log_b)/2) instead?

Answer (score -1):

Use http://wolframalpha.com . For example, as discussed by Mysticial, your calculation of
log(exp(-1.6430e+03) + exp(-3.8278e+03)/2) is approximately equal to log_a.  More precisely it equals...

1642.9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999288154175193167154874243862288962865800888654829363675488466381404578225092913407982036991983506370017587380105049077722517705727311433458060227246074261903850589008701929721367650576354241270720062760800558681236724831345952032973775644175750495894596292205385323394564549904750849335403418234531787942293155499938538026848481952030717783105220543888597195156662520697417952130625416040662694927878196360733032741542418365527213770518383992577797346467266676866552563022498785887306273550235307330535082355570343750317349638125974233837177558240980392298326807001406291035229026016040567173260205109683449441154277953394697235601979288239733693137185710713089424316870093563207034737497769711306780243623361236030692934897720786516684985651633787662244416960982457075265287065358586526093347161275192566468776617613339812566918101457823704547101340270795298909954224594...